# Twitter v1.1: 400 Bad request

Tags: twitter

I have problems with the new Twitter API: v1.0 is working without problems, but if I change the URL to v1.1 I get all the time a error "400 Bad request" (seen with Firebug).

Example:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi

This is working like a charm, everything works as excepted. 
Simply changing the URL to `.../1.1/...` and I get a Bad request error and even to JSON error response or even some content at all.

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi)

Note: It couldn't be a rate limitation, because I accessed the URL the first time ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi redirects me to https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi

Looks like `1.1` is the same thing as `1`

**UPD:** [Looks like this is a rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835067/twitter-api-always-saying-400-bad-request) (as `1.1` link worked for me 2 hours ago). Even if you hit API page for the first time, some of your apps (descktop or mobile) could use API methods.

**UPD2:** in **1.1** 400 Bad request means you are not autorized (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#user-context). So you need to get user context

Comment: In no browser I use (Firefox, Chrome) I'll be redirected. What browser do you use? `1` will be shut down on March 5th, 2013. It isn't the same like `1.1` - take a look over here: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/current-status-api-v1.1

Comment: @Poru, Looks like a twitter API bug. Now I'm getting `400 Bad Request` too.

Comment: I think it was the missing user context + lib bugs. I switched my lib to Zend_Service_Twitter which works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate and authorize using oauth before using v1.1 apis
Here is something which works with python tweepy - gets statuses from users timeline

```
def twitter_fetch(screen_name = "BBCNews",maxnumtweets=10):
   'Fetch tweets from @BBCNews'
    # API described at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

    consumer_token = '' #substitute values from twitter website
    consumer_secret = ''
    access_token = ''
    access_secret = ''

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

    api  = tweepy.API(auth)
    #print api.me().name
    #api.update_status('Hello -tweepy + oauth!')

    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(2):
        print status.text+'\n'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_fetch('BBCNews',10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was the size of the media that was attached to the tweet. If it was <1.2MB it went through OK, but if it was over, I would get a 400 error every time.

Strange considering Twitter says the tweet limit is 3MB https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-media-parameter-is-invalid-after-successfully-uploading-media/58354